# Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

`Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.OMDOMMetaFactory overrides final method createSOAPMessage.(Lorg/apache/axiom/om/OMXMLParserWrapper;)Lorg/apache/axiom/soap/SOAPMessage;. Please see server.log for more details.`

How can I overcome this error?I use Java MVC and Tomcat server.

Comment: Maybe you could "see server.log for more details"?

Answer (score 0):

That error may occur if you mix JARs from different versions of Apache Axiom.